# Why my android app doesn't scale to fullscreen on real Display?

Tags: android, scale, display, dimensions

[image: On real display (1080p)]
[image: On dev tool]

I don't know why. 
1. I try to change my Display from 1080p to 4K but it not work
2. On my dev tool, I choose device is HD1080, API23, Scale is Panel, Scaletype: fitXY and disable adjustViewBounds.

Thank so much.

Comment: I don't know why... I tried to many way.